# The Events Calendar tribe_get_event() returning null date

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, calendar

I'm writing a plugin that integrates with **The Events Calendar** and the **SendGrid** API to send email when an event is published.  It uses `tribe_get_event($post)` to grab the event, then passes it along to the mailer class like this:

```
public function setEvent(?\WP_Post $event): self
{
    if (! $event) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->eventTitle = $event->post_title;
    $this->eventDate = date('F jS, Y', strtotime($event->start_date));
    $this->eventPermalink = get_permalink($event);

    return $this;
}
```

This works perfectly on my dev machine, but the start date comes through as **January 1st, 1970** in production.  I've tried replacing `$event->start_date` with `tribe_get_start_date($event)` with exactly the same result.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

For reference...
Dev machine: MacBook Pro with PHP 8.2.2, MySql 8.0.27, nginx 1.23.3
Production: Debian GNU/Linux with PHP 8.1.19, MySql 8.0.22, ??
Both: The Events Calendar 6.1.2.2

Comment: There's a missing closing parentheses on the `date()` call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it was just a mis-copy.  The code would not have worked at all without that paren.

Comment: What is the value of `$event->start_date`? Possible it's in a format that `strtotime()` can't interpret.

Comment: I debugged the s*** out of it and was not able to isolate the problem.  It now works, and I don't know why.  Fortunately, this is for private consumption, so it's cool.